# How can one prove that the algebra of smooth functions is semisimple?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, differential-topology

I have read in some differential geometry works that the ring of smooth functions $C^{\infty}(U)$ is a semi-simple ring, for $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ an open set; right now I can cite a remark immediately preceding Proposition 2.4.1 on Kostant's notes "Graded Manifolds, graded Lie theory and prequantisation".

How can one prove such a thing? Is there anywhere I can find this result for citation purposes?

This question earned me the "Tumbleweed" badge at math.SE; I hope it doesn't happen in here! Here's the link for math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318033/proof-and-reference-if-possible-of-semisimplicity-of-the-ring-of-smooth-functi

Thanks a lot! Cheers!

Comment: By semisimple you mean "trivial Jacobson radical", right? (and not what the ring theorists often call "semisimple")

Comment: If indeed you mean (or Kostant meant) that the Jacobson radical is zero, this is trivial: the functions vanishing at one point form a maximal ideal of $C^{\infty}(U)$, and the intersection of these ideals is clearly $(0)$.

Comment: Choi: what ring theorists call "semisimple" is equivalent (as far as I know) to "trivial Jacobson radical". 
abx: Spot on! You are right, it slipped my mind. Please answer the question (even if it's trivial) so I can mark it. Cheers!

Comment: Regarding the previous comment: that used to be my belief, but then I kept finding that algebraists I talked to would interpret "semisimple" to mean "*artinian* and has trivial Jacobson radical"

Comment: Nowadays most ring theorist use semiprimitive to mean trivial jacobson radical and semisimple to mean the regular module is semisimple which is equivalent to semiprimitive and Artinian.